# In drop down menu option is selecting in two clicks in windowphone8.1 But i want to select the option in onclick only?

Tags: javascript, android, html, windows, dojo

1. drop down code in my project

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <select>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. In first click, getting some flashes which is in app .
3. In second click, its selecting. In android, iPhone works fine Except windows phone 8.1
4. I am using totally dojo, Worklight, Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure but Have you tried by preventing the default behavior and added your code there. Like event.preventDefault(), it may stop the usual behavior of window phone and then you can call your onclick method.